# How do I place a unique ID in my PHP confirmation page?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that emails me the results from a form that generates a unique ID number. The PHP script executes a confirmation page.  I'm trying to place the unique ID on the confirmation page: quote_confirm.php.  I already tried this in the conformation page:

> ```
>  <?php
>     $prefix = 'LPFQ';
>     $uniqid = $prefix . uniqid();
>     $QuoteID = strtoupper($uniqid);
> ```

```
    ."<tr><td class=\"label\"><strong>Quote ID:</strong></td><td>".$QuoteID."</td></tr>\n"
```

Comment: is the confirmation page the page as the email script?

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly

Comment: If you do not get an answer, or an appropriate answer, straight away, please do not repost your question. It is almost certain that someone will look at your question who will have the correct answer - it just may take a little time. Also, if you feel you need an answer more quickly, mechanisms are in place for that - such as the bounty system (see the FAQ section of the site for more information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `uniqid()` has a prefix parameter, so your line `$uniqid = $prefix . uniqid();` should actually be `$uniqid = uniqid($prefix);`

Also, are you receiving an error? What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand it is something like this:

form -> mail + output page

So there is mail()-like function and after that some output.

If the variable(`$uniqid`) is set you have to make sure it's not overwritten or unset by something else before the actual output. You have to also check the scope of variable.

There is no mistake in the code you posted.

But speaking of style:

I also recommend using using `$uniqid = uniqid($prefix)` instead of `$uniqid = $prefix. uniqid();`.
And the following line is strange:

`."<tr><td class=\"label\"><strong>Quote ID:</strong></td><td>".$QuoteID."</td></tr>\n"`

Write it as `"<tr><td class=\"label\"><strong>Quote ID:</strong></td><td>$QuoteID</td></tr>\n"` (if you insist on using `""`) and if the function is echo (example: `echo $something` not `$content .= $something`) use `,` instead of `.` .

Full example:

`echo 'Constant text without variables', $variable, "String with a $variable and a newline \n";`

Comment: You used a variable within double-quotes which is very, very slow. You should never do that. `$var = "this" . $something;` is about as fast as `$var = 'this' . $something;` but `$var = "this$something";` is a LOT slower.

Comment: I try to avoid "$variables", but I put it as an example what could be done in some situations (if you don't mind the speed and just want a few variables in long text, like the output of long-running script in php-cli). The best way is still `echo 'Constant', $variable;` and `$var = 'constant'. $variable;` if you don't want the output. The only *practical* use for `""` is to put special characters like `"\n"`.